# UIScrollView Crashing after ReloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

i have ScrollView in every row of tableView. i am assigning different tag to it.
it works perfectly for the first time. when change data in array and make ReloadData App Crashes.

Error is like

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Piece of code

```
 cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContentCell", for: indexPath)
                let lblName = (cell.viewWithTag(31)! as! UILabel)
                let lblSubmited = (cell.viewWithTag(32)! as! UILabel)
                let lblFrom = (cell.viewWithTag(33)! as! UILabel)
                let lblTo = (cell.viewWithTag(34)! as! UILabel)
                let lblTotalHours = (cell.viewWithTag(35)! as! UILabel)
                let lblapprove = (cell.viewWithTag(36)! as! UILabel)

                lblName.text = dict.object(forKey: "name") as? String
                lblSubmited.text = dict.object(forKey: "submitted") as? String
                lblFrom.text = dict.object(forKey: "from") as? String
                lblTo.text = dict.object(forKey: "to") as? String
                lblTotalHours.text = dict.object(forKey: "tot") as? String
                lblapprove.text = "Pending"

                let scrollView:UIScrollView!
                if(flag.object(at: indexPath.row) as! String == "0"){
                        scrollView = (cell.viewWithTag(3)! as! UIScrollView)
                        scrollView.tag = ((100 * indexPath.row)+1)
                        flag.replaceObject(at: indexPath.row, with: "1")
                }
                else{
                    scrollView = (cell.viewWithTag(((100 * indexPath.row)+1))! as! UIScrollView)
                }

            scrollView.delegate = self
            scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

            let viewContent = (cell.viewWithTag(1000)!)
            let btApprove = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 704.0, y: 10.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
            let btReject = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 788.0, y: 10.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))
            let btDetail = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 860.0, y: 10.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0))

            btApprove.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.approvePressedAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            btReject.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.rejectPressedAction), for: .touchUpInside)
            btDetail.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.detailPressedAction), for: .touchUpInside)

            viewContent.addSubview(btApprove)
            viewContent.addSubview(btReject)
            viewContent.addSubview(btDetail)

  return cell
```

error comes  in

> scrollView = (cell.viewWithTag(3)! as! UIScrollView)

line and crashes after reloadData. Any Solution?

Comment: po cell.viewWithTag(3) while in debug mode to know its class. You may be typecasting wrong view to UIScrollView.

Comment: working perfectly . type casting is not issue.

Comment: it crash only after ReloadData.

Comment: @Rushi it's not working perfectly or you wouldn't have a crash.

Comment: @wez do u have answer?

Comment: i think Problem is like ScrollView tag which is inside tableView are not refreshed by ReloadData. maybe any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are forcing a lot of optionals to un-wrap, maybe check them first before trying to use them.

**I have no idea what your logic is doing, but to run some checks on the specific line that crashes try something like this.**

```
var scrollView:UIScrollView!
if(flag.object(at: indexPath.row) as! String == "0"){
    if let view = cell.viewWithTag(3) {
        if let sv = view as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView = sv
            scrollView.tag = ((100 * indexPath.row)+1)
            flag.replaceObject(at: indexPath.row, with: "1")
        } else {
            print("view found with tag 3 but it's not a scrollview")
        }
    } else {
        print("no view found with tag 3")
    }
} else {
    scrollView = (cell.viewWithTag(((100 * indexPath.row)+1))! as! UIScrollView)
}
```

Comment: logic of tag only for Scrolling all row at once through ScrollViewDidScroll.

Comment: Did you try running the checks? what happened?

Comment: first time working. after reloadData "no view found with tag 3" why ?

Comment: how to reload ScrollViewTag to default 3 from outlet.

Comment: I don't know sorry, your example does not explain your full issue. use these check to resolve it yourself. debugging is part of a development.

Comment: Thanks for helping.

Comment: it remove crash. because There is no tag number 3 second time. no need to initialize scrollview only configure data with tableview.